# Consume WCF Rest Service (JSON) using C# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, rest, c#-4.0

I'm having difficulty consuming a WCF REST service, which returns JSON, in a C# ASP.NET MVC application.  I'm trying to consume the service in a Controller.  I have a ASP.NET MVC project and a service project in the same solution.  I've created an entry in my local IIS which points to the service project (i.e. http://localhost/SampleService/).The WCF Service works because I can access the URL and the correct JSON is returned.

Does anyone have any code samples on consuming the JSON via a Controller from a RESTful WCF Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used WebChannelFactory and it worked great.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the DataContractJsonSerializer:

Here's an example:

```
var client = new WebClient();
var data = client.DownloadData("http://localhost/SampleService/GetJsonMessage");
var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
var obj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(string));
var result = obj.ReadObject(stream).ToString();
```

In your controller you can do this to view the result

```
return Content(result.ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the built-in `DataContractJsonSerializer`, or the JSON.NET library's `JsonSerializer`.

I prefer the latter, because it is more robust. Sometimes the `DataContractJsonSerializer` cannot deserialize a JSON object.

Sample code:

```
Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(jsonText);
```

To download the library, go to http://json.codeplex.com/